# Move [infragistics] to the infraworld

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

As far as I know, tags about companies are off-topic, yet we have [infragistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infragistics), which info says:

> Infragistics is a company that specializes in User Interface (UI) controls and components for .NET, ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF, Silverlight, jQuery, Angular 2, iOS, Android, UWP, Xamarin, etc.

It's certainly as helpful as tagging with [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) or [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google).

To answer the common questions:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**
   No, it doesn't tell me anything about the question. It could be a WPF (Windows Desktop) problem or an iOS problem.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   No, discussions about companies are not on-topic.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   Not really, only the tag of the actual product being used would be relevant.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   It certainly does not, given that you cannot even know if the question is about a web, desktop or mobile problem.

Can we burninate (and probably blacklist) this tag?

Comment: The description is subpotimal, but isn't the product called "Infragistics Ultimate" or "Infragistics Professional"? Maybe changing the description is enough.

Comment: @BDL There's an "Infragistics Ultimate" product (one of many), but that's far from the current tag and it is still useless for a question

Comment: I disagree, Infragistics is a pretty small tag that receives attention only thanks its name, removing that tag will leave without a proper classification questions about its components and makes a lot harder for experts on these tools find those questions. How do you plan to replace a question about Infragistics UltraWinGrid, UltraToolBar, Ultra XXXXX many other tools produced by that company?. And what about then for DevExpress, ComponentOne, Telerik and other small companies specialized in the component market? It is unfair to compare against Google or Microsoft.

Comment: @Steve Well, there's a reason tags like microsoft, google and apple were banned, right? If I tag with [tag:visual-studio], is there any reason to need [tag:microsoft] as well? Why not [tag:infragistics-ultratoolbar] or [tag:ultratoolbar]? I'd hold the same feeling for DevExpress and Telerik

Comment: Because I need to add tens of different tags to my favorites? And then check the questions one by one? Now that we don't have anymore the old navigation bar this will be really a bad blow for everyone that looks at those questions. I repeat the same point. It is not the same thing when you put on the same level the confusion created by he _microsoft_ tag and the _infragistics_ one.

Comment: I completely agree with @Steve. microsoft and apple are problematic because you never know which of their product the question belongs to. But since infragistics just has this one product (and also named it Infragistics Ultimate) it's not the same situation. We could discuss renaming the tag to "infragistics-ultimate", but I don't see any real value in doing so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change the tag excerpt:

> For questions about the User Interface (UI) controls and components from Infragistics for .NET, jQuery, iOS, Android, UWP, Xamarin, etc. Add an platform/stack specific tag to scope the question correctly for the right audience.

Or something along these lines.

Although the tag *describes* the company, the majority of the question is about the product(s) made by that company. If you assess *Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?* you have to look at the questions, not only at what the tag describes.

A similar reasoning can be followed for [telerik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telerik), the tag advertises the company, the tagging of question is correct in the majority of cases.

Don't burninate *only* on what the tag says, it is the content in the tag that should provide the evidence that the tag is not OK/misused.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it talks more about the general situation with tags than with infragistics in particular. Thanks for the insight, will take it into account!

Comment: Done, please review to fix.

Answer (score 3):

Think of Infragistics as a library name because that's what it really is.  There is some ambiguity between the different platform targets of their stuff, but ultimately Infragistics is a library of UI controls.

A quick look at some of the questions with this tag disproves burnination points 2 and 3.  You'll notice that the questions ask about coding components from a library:

- [Infragistics grid : row overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978434/infragistics-grid-row-overlapping)
- [Change the LabelTemplate on an Infragistics XamDoughnutChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814237/change-the-labeltemplate-on-an-infragistics-xamdoughnutchart)
- [How to get Regular Expression in IgGrid cell (Infragistics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832828/how-to-get-regular-expression-in-iggrid-cell-infragistics)

If you really wanted to make the various flavors of Infragistics library distinct, you could split the tag into platform-specific versions.  For example `infragistics-winforms` or `infragistics-xaml` or whatever the appropriate namespace is.